Stratum connection example
I'm trying to figure out what each parameter does in stratum. I've looked through the internet, but haven't found an agreement on what each parameter does. I have a wireshark dump of CCminer connecting to the pool, subscribing and authorizing, getting mining.set_target and mining.notify and submitting a share, but I can't figure out what exactly is each parameter in the packets. What are the parameters inside the methods? (for example I know mining.authorize uses username and password)

Is it possible that your question is "Where can I find documentation for Stratum V1?"
